# Relation 3 tables (laravel 5.7)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 table like this image. I want get specify pet with race and get owner of  this pet. How can i get all the three records from pets.

[image]

I have try

Pets::find($id)->races()->with(users)->get();

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'id');
}

public function races()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Races', 'id', 'id');
}
```

Thx for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when you have a [something]_id it indicates the row **belongs to** another row.

Change the relationships in your `Pets` model to be:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function race()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Races');
}
```

Then to get the `user` and `race` you can do:

```
Pets::with('user', 'race')->find($id);
```

or since you're only getting loading the one `Pet` here you can simply do:

```
$pet = Pets::find($id);
```

and you will have access to `$pet->user` and `$pet->race` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

if you have pets model you should add belong to user and also belong to `pets_reces` in it

and try `Pets::find($id)->races;`
or `Pets::find($id)->users;`

another way is to get user id or race id and then get all pets from it with out create model for pets so you can add belong to many in users and races.

Comment: set the question is solve and set the answer as top or rate - evaluate it @Unmecparla